# Remove ? and / at the end of urls

Tags: .htaccess

I noticed that my urls are duplicated (or better to say triplicated). I've 3 versions of the same page, something like:

`www.example.com/cars/mercedes`

`www.example.com/cars/mercedes?`

`www.example.com/cars/mercedes/`

I'ld like redirect [301] the urls ending with `?` and `/` to the clean version.

I've already set a canonical tags to `www.example.com/cars/mercedes` but anyway the pages are still reachable from the other two versions and I don't like this.

I tried something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ? HTTP [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} / HTTP [NC]
RewriteRule .? http(s)?://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Do you say? However I'ld prefer to fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^?]*)[?/]\s
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [NE,R=301,L]
```

This will remove trailing `/` or `?` from your URL.

**Make sure to test it after clearing your browser cache.**